# memory leak with clock() on Xcode on OSX

Tags: c, xcode, macos, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm working in Xcode and the Instruments static analysis found a surprising memory leaks of 160 kb.

This call is to `clock()` from `time.h`, the C standard lib. I'm not using pointers or `free()`.

Did I miss / forget something?

### simple main function with `clock()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();
    start = clock() - start;
    fprintf(stderr, "Elasped time %f\n\n", (float)(start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Software version:

- Xcode: Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t)
- Instruments: Version 7.0 (7A165t)

I get the same issue with Xcode v6.3 (6D570) and Instruments Version 6.3 (6D570)

I can't understand. I tried searching and finding an existing question, with no luck. :(

Comment: Does the *actual program* posted cause a memory leak?

Comment: The posted code does not cause a memory leak on OS X compiled with `clang` or `gcc`. I also do not see any memory leaks in XCode 6.4 with Instruments.

Comment: And if you're using Instruments, you can get a stack back-trace of the place where memory is allegedly leaked.

Comment: Ok thanks all for your helps.

I look with a new project on Xcode. With my macbook and iMac I have always this leaks memory.

I'm beginner, and it possible I have miss something

I compile the main.c with gcc on terminal, and see what happens with instruments (see picture below)

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/767414instruments.png